# How to change the default theme in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-theme

Every time I go to xml file I've to change my theme first to see how my views will actually look, my parent theme is inheriting from MaterialComponents theme and all of the activities are using the same base theme, but still I don't know why in xml it shows Material.Light as my default theme.

[image]

and AppTheme is the theme that I want to set to default, is there any way I can do that.

Comment: Hey @rahul-pawar. Did you find a solution for changing default theme?